# How to Remove data in the table

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGLV1.jpg)

I have the data stored first in the temporary table.

id temp | type | id service

I want to delete the data per id in the append table, but when deleting the data, the data is not erased

controller

```
public function delete_append($id){
  $this->M_outbound->delete_db_temp($id);
  redirect ('backend/outbound');
 }
```

model

```
public function delete_db_temp($id){
return $this->db->delete('temporary', array('id_tmp' => $id));
}
```

form

```
$(".btntmp").click(function(){ //input append
      var id_service       = $("input[name='id_service']").val(); //tracking_number
      var id_inbound_detail = $("input[name='id_inbound_detail']").val();
      var kd_outbound      = $("input[name='kd_outbound']").val();
      var tracking_number  = $("input[name='tracking_number']").val();
      var nama_cs          = $("input[name='nama_cs']").val();
      var tgl_outbound     = $("input[name='tgl_outbound']").val();
      var id_cs            = $("#customers").val();
      var nama_kecamatan   = $("input[name='nama_kecamatan']").val();

      $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo base_url();?>backend/outbound/add_tmp', //add data
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         data: {
                id_service: id_service, 
                id_inbound_detail: id_inbound_detail, 
                kd_outbound: kd_outbound, 
                tracking_number: tracking_number, 
                nama_cs: nama_cs, 
                id_cs: id_cs, 
                kd_outbound: kd_outbound, 
                tgl_outbound: tgl_outbound, 
                nama_kecamatan: nama_kecamatan,
                },
         error: function() {
         },
         success: function(data) {
          if(data.sukses==false){
            alert(data.pesan);
          }else{
            $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+nama_cs+"</td><td>"+tracking_number+"</td><td>"+kd_outbound+"</td><td>"+tgl_outbound+"</td><td>"+nama_kecamatan+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>"); 
          }
        }
    });
});


$("#tbody").on("click", ".btn-delete", function(){ 
$(this).parents("tr").remove(); //button not delete in database

});
```

Comment: Could you show how you write the html form?

Answer (score 1):

With the code provided you are just hiding the "deleted" row by clicking the red button, but you are not calling the PHP function.

In the click event of the delete button you should call your PHP code via AJAX or something like this (not tested):

```
$("#tbody").on("click", ".btn-delete", function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>backend/outbound/delete_tmp",
        success: function(result) {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```